# nix flakes: what is the difference between `nix build git+file:.` and `nix build path:.`

Tags: nix, nixos, nix-flake

this is a continuation of https://discourse.nixos.org/t/can-i-use-flakes-within-a-git-repo-without-committing-flake-nix/18196/37?u=srghma

IF I enable `nix flakes`
AND I am in the in the git repo

I found the following behavior

> IF I do `nix build .` THEN nix will try to find the [type](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-flake.html#types) of directory `.`
>
> - IF `./.git` THEN type is `git`
> - IF `./.something-else-dont-know` THEN type is `mercurial`
> - ...
> - IF nothing is found THEN type is `path`
>
> but I can force nix to use specific type by using `nix build git+file:.` or  `nix build path:.`

---

QUESTION:

1. what is the difference?
2. what is `self-contained` / `hermetic evaluation`?
3. `git-flake-evaluation` is `hermetic`, but is `path-flake-evaluation` `hermetic`?
4. does `nix build git+file:.` have some additional caching, that `nix build path:.` doesnt have?
5. why not make `nix build .` just equal to `nix build path:.`, instead of this `find type automatically` behavior, described above <sub>(Because: what problem its trying to solve? The problem, solutions to which require all these weird behaviors, like unsolicited `git add` behind the scenes? But I can easily get around/silence it with `path:.`? This nix-flakes design is so weird, reason is so shady)</sub>

Comment: This is a kind of question you can better ask on the Discourse.

Comment: I don't agree completely. Question "how and why it works" is perfectly fine for stack overflow, it's just the only person that knows the answer is Eelco Dolstra. He could answer in 1 post. But he will probably not see this question, so we resort to discussions.

Comment: I have found that answer on "why" is that the "flakes ARE repositories" was the original idea of Eelco Dolstra. This answers question "why nix does git add in a shadowly manner". But, again, "why?"